# Shopify slideshow, want to make the slide with video last as long as the video

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow, shopify

I have a shopify store I'm working on . 
https://www.bonmarcheonline.com/ 
I want to slideshow to stop on the second slide for the duration of the video then revert back to the first slide and stay there.

Heres the html

```
{% assign slider_enabled = true %}
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    {% for i in (1..6) %}
      {% capture slide %}slide_{{ i }}{% endcapture %}
      {% capture slide_link %}slide_{{ i }}_link{% endcapture %}
      {% capture slide_img%}slide_{{ i }}{% endcapture %}
      {% capture slide_alt %}slide_{{ i }}_alt{% endcapture %}
      {% if settings[slide] %}

    <li><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1418/7648/files/slide1.jpg?17428083521508450295">
    <div class="banner_title">
          <h1>A colorful lifestyle</h1>
          <div class="banner-button">
          <a href="https://www.bonmarcheonline.com/collections/best-sellers?sort_by=best-selling{{ settings[slide_link] }}">shop now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
      </li>
    <li><iframe div class="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NQFGjQ-gVJw?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></li>
          <a href="{{ settings[slide_link] }}" class="slide-link">
            {{ slide_img | asset_img_url: '1920x1024' | img_tag: settings[slide_alt] }}
          </a>
          <div class="banner_title">
          <h1>A colorful lifestyle</h1>
          <div class="banner-button">
          <a href="{{ settings[slide_link] }}">shop now</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
    </div>
```

The CSS

```
.unslider {
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.unslider-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.unslider-wrap.unslider-carousel > li {
  float: left;
}
.unslider-vertical > ul {
  height: 100%;
}
.unslider-vertical li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.unslider-fade {
  position: relative;
}
.unslider-fade .unslider-wrap li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 8;
}
.unslider-fade .unslider-wrap li.unslider-active {
  z-index: 10;
}
.unslider ul, .unslider ol, .unslider li {
  list-style: none;
  /* Reset any weird spacing */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}
.unslider-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.unslider-arrow.next {
  left: auto;
  right: 20px;
}

.unslider-nav ol {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.unslider-nav ol li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -999em;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.unslider-nav ol li.unslider-active {
  background: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Here is the javascript

```
window.timberSlider = window.timberSlider || {};

timberSlider.cacheSelectors = function () {
  timberSlider.cache = {
    // Home Page
    $slider: $('.flexslider')
  }
};

timberSlider.init = function () {
  timberSlider.cacheSelectors();
  timberSlider.sliders();
};

timberSlider.sliders = function () {
  var $slider = timberSlider.cache.$slider,
      sliderArgs = {
        animation: '{{ settings.slider_home_transition }}',
        animationSpeed: 500,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        keyboard: false,
        slideshow: {{ settings.slider_home_auto }},
        slideshowSpeed: {{ settings.slider_home_rate }},
        controlNav: {{ settings.slider_home_show_dots }},
        smoothHeight: true
      };

  if ($slider.length) {


 if ($slider.find('li').length === 3) {
      sliderArgs.slideshow = false;
      sliderArgs.slideshowSpeed = 0;
      sliderArgs.controlNav = false;
      sliderArgs.directionNav = false;
    }  

    $slider.flexslider(sliderArgs);
  }

};


// Initialize slider on docready
$(window).on('load', function() {
  timberSlider.init();
});
```

The jquery

```
!function(a){a.flexslider=function(b,c){var d=a(b);d.vars=a.extend({},a.flexslider.defaults,c);var j,e=d.vars.namespace,f=window.navigator&&window.navigator.msPointerEnabled&&window.MSGesture,g=("ontouchstart"in window||f||window.DocumentTouch&&document instanceof DocumentTouch)&&d.vars.touch,h="click touchend MSPointerUp",i="",k="vertical"===d.vars.direction,l=d.vars.reverse,m=d.vars.itemWidth>0,n="fade"===d.vars.animation,o=""!==d.vars.asNavFor,p={},q=!0;a.data(b,"flexslider",d),p={init:function(){d.animating=!1,d.currentSlide=parseInt(d.vars.startAt?d.vars.startAt:0,10),isNaN(d.currentSlide)&&(d.currentSlide=0),d.animatingTo=d.currentSlide,d.atEnd=0===d.currentSlide||d.currentSlide===d.last,d.containerSelector=d.vars.selector.substr(0,d.vars.selector.search(" ")),d.slides=a(d.vars.selector,d),d.container=a(d.containerSelector,d),d.count=d.slides.length,d.syncExists=a(d.vars.sync).length>0,"slide"===d.vars.animation&&(d.vars.animation="swing"),d.prop=k?"top":"marginLeft",d.args={},d.manualPause=!1,d.stopped=!1,d.started=!1,d.startTimeout=null,d.transitions=!d.vars.video&&!n&&d.vars.useCSS&&function(){var a=document.createElement("div"),b=["perspectiveProperty","WebkitPerspective","MozPerspective","OPerspective","msPerspective"];for(var c in b)if(void 0!==a.style[b[c]])return d.pfx=b[c].replace("Perspective","").toLowerCase(),d.prop="-"+d.pfx+"-transform",!0;return!1}(),d.ensureAnimationEnd="",""!==d.vars.controlsContainer&&(d.controlsContainer=a(d.vars.controlsContainer).length>0&&a(d.vars.controlsContainer)),""!==d.vars.manualControls&&(d.manualControls=a(d.vars.manualControls).length>0&&a(d.vars.manualControls)),d.vars.randomize&&(d.slides.sort(function(){return Math.round(Math.random())-.5}),d.container.empty().append(d.slides)),d.doMath(),d.setup("init"),d.vars.controlNav&&p.controlNav.setup(),d.vars.directionNav&&p.directionNav.setup(),d.vars.keyboard&&(1===a(d.containerSelector).length||d.vars.multipleKeyboard)&&a(document).bind("keyup",function(a){var b=a.keyCode;if(!d.animating&&(39===b||37===b)){var c=39===b?d.getTarget("next"):37===b?d.getTarget("prev"):!1;d.flexAnimate(c,d.vars.pauseOnAction)}}),d.vars.mousewheel&&d.bind("mousewheel",function(a,b){a.preventDefault();var f=0>b?d.getTarget("next"):d.getTarget("prev");d.flexAnimate(f,d.vars.pauseOnAction)}),d.vars.pausePlay&&p.pausePlay.setup(),d.vars.slideshow&&d.vars.pauseInvisible&&p.pauseInvisible.init(),d.vars.slideshow&&(d.vars.pauseOnHover&&d.hover(function(){d.manualPlay||d.manualPause||d.pause()},function(){d.manualPause||d.manualPlay||d.stopped||d.play()}),d.vars.pauseInvisible&&p.pauseInvisible.isHidden()||(d.vars.initDelay>0?d.startTimeout=setTimeout(d.play,d.vars.initDelay):d.play())),o&&p.asNav.setup(),g&&d.vars.touch&&p.touch(),(!n||n&&d.vars.smoothHeight)&&a(window).bind("resize orientationchange focus",p.resize),d.find("img").attr("draggable","false"),setTimeout(function(){d.vars.start(d)},200)},asNav:{setup:function(){d.asNav=!0,d.animatingTo=Math.floor(d.currentSlide/d.move),d.currentItem=d.currentSlide,d.slides.removeClass(e+"active-slide").eq(d.currentItem).addClass(e+"active-slide"),f?(b._slider=d,d.slides.each(function(){var b=this;b._gesture=new MSGesture,b._gesture.target=b,b.addEventListener("MSPointerDown",function(a){a.preventDefault(),a.currentTarget._gesture&&a.currentTarget._gesture.addPointer(a.pointerId)},!1),b.addEventListener("MSGestureTap",function(b){b.preventDefault();var c=a(this),e=c.index();a(d.vars.asNavFor).data("flexslider").animating||c.hasClass("active")||(d.direction=d.currentItem<e?"next":"prev",d.flexAnimate(e,d.vars.pauseOnAction,!1,!0,!0))})})):d.slides.on(h,function(b){b.preventDefault();var c=a(this),f=c.index(),g=c.offset().left-a(d).scrollLeft();0>=g&&c.hasClass(e+"active-slide")?d.flexAnimate(d.getTarget("prev"),!0):a(d.vars.asNavFor).data("flexslider").animating||c.hasClass(e+"active-slide")||(d.direction=d.currentItem<f?"next":"prev",d.flexAnimate(f,d.vars.pauseOnAction,!1,!0,!0))})}},controlNav:{setup:function(){d.manualControls?p.controlNav.setupManual():p.controlNav.setupPaging()},setupPaging:function(){var f,g,b="thumbnails"===d.vars.controlNav?"control-thumbs":"control-paging",c=1;if(d.controlNavScaffold=a('<ol class="'+e+"control-nav "+e+b+'"></ol>'),d.pagingCount>1)for(var j=0;j<d.pagingCount;j++){if(g=d.slides.eq(j),f="thumbnails"===d.vars.controlNav?'<img src="'+g.attr("data-thumb")+'"/>':"<a>"+c+"</a>","thumbnails"===d.vars.controlNav&&!0===d.vars.thumbCaptions){var k=g.attr("data-thumbcaption");""!=k&&void 0!=k&&(f+='<span class="'+e+'caption">'+k+"</span>")}d.controlNavScaffold.append("<li>"+f+"</li>"),c++}d.controlsContainer?a(d.controlsContainer).append(d.controlNavScaffold):d.append(d.controlNavScaffold),p.controlNav.set(),p.controlNav.active(),d.controlNavScaffold.delegate("a, img",h,function(b){if(b.preventDefault(),""===i||i===b.type){var c=a(this),f=d.controlNav.index(c);c.hasClass(e+"active")||(d.direction=f>d.currentSlide?"next":"prev",d.flexAnimate(f,d.vars.pauseOnAction))}""===i&&(i=b.type),p.setToClearWatchedEvent()})},setupManual:function(){d.controlNav=d.manualControls,p.controlNav.active(),d.controlNav.bind(h,function(b){if(b.preventDefault(),""===i||i===b.type){var c=a(this),f=d.controlNav.index(c);c.hasClass(e+"active")||(d.direction=f>d.currentSlide?"next":"prev",d.flexAnimate(f,d.vars.pauseOnAction))}""===i&&(i=b.type),p.setToClearWatchedEvent()})},set:function(){var b="thumbnails"===d.vars.controlNav?"img":"a";d.controlNav=a("."+e+"control-nav li "+b,d.controlsContainer?d.controlsContainer:d)},active:function(){d.controlNav.removeClass(e+"active").eq(d.animatingTo).addClass(e+"active")},update:function(b,c){d.pagingCount>1&&"add"===b?d.controlNavScaffold.append(a("<li><a>"+d.count+"</a></li>")):1===d.pagingCount?d.controlNavScaffold.find("li").remove():d.controlNav.eq(c).closest("li").remove(),p.controlNav.set(),d.pagingCount>1&&d.pagingCount!==d.controlNav.length?d.update(c,b):p.controlNav.active()}},directionNav:{setup:function(){var b=a('<ul class="'+e+'direction-nav"><li><a class="'+e+'prev" href="#">'+d.vars.prevText+'</a></li><li><a class="'+e+'next" href="#">'+d.vars.nextText+"</a></li></ul>");d.controlsContainer?(a(d.controlsContainer).append(b),d.directionNav=a("."+e+"direction-nav li a",d.controlsContainer)):(d.append(b),d.directionNav=a("."+e+"direction-nav li a",d)),p.directionNav.update(),d.directionNav.bind(h,function(b){b.preventDefault();var c;(""===i||i===b.type)&&(c=a(this).hasClass(e+"next")?d.getTarget("next"):d.getTarget("prev"),d.flexAnimate(c,d.vars.pauseOnAction)),""===i&&(i=b.type),p.setToClearWatchedEvent()})},update:function(){var a=e+"disabled";1===d.pagingCount?d.directionNav.addClass(a).attr("tabindex","-1"):d.vars.animationLoop?d.directionNav.removeClass(a).removeAttr("tabindex"):0===d.animatingTo?d.directionNav.removeClass(a).filter("."+e+"prev").addClass(a).attr("tabindex","-1"):d.animatingTo===d.last?d.directionNav.removeClass(a).filter("."+e+"next").addClass(a).attr("tabindex","-1"):d.directionNav.removeClass(a).removeAttr("tabindex")}},pausePlay:{setup:function(){var b=a('<div class="'+e+'pauseplay"><a></a></div>');d.controlsContainer?(d.controlsContainer.append(b),d.pausePlay=a("."+e+"pauseplay a",d.controlsContainer)):(d.append(b),d.pausePlay=a("."+e+"pauseplay a",d)),p.pausePlay.update(d.vars.slideshow?e+"pause":e+"play"),d.pausePlay.bind(h,function(b){b.preventDefault(),(""===i||i===b.type)&&(a(this).hasClass(e+"pause")?(d.manualPause=!0,d.manualPlay=!1,d.pause()):(d.manualPause=!1,d.manualPlay=!0,d.play())),""===i&&(i=b.type),p.setToClearWatchedEvent()})},update:function(a){"play"===a?d.pausePlay.removeClass(e+"pause").addClass(e+"play").html(d.vars.playText):d.pausePlay.removeClass(e+"play").addClass(e+"pause").html(d.vars.pauseText)}},touch:function(){function r(f){d.animating?f.preventDefault():(window.navigator.msPointerEnabled||1===f.touches.length)&&(d.pause(),g=k?d.h:d.w,i=Number(new Date),o=f.touches[0].pageX,p=f.touches[0].pageY,e=m&&l&&d.animatingTo===d.last?0:m&&l?d.limit-(d.itemW+d.vars.itemMargin)*d.move*d.animatingTo:m&&d.currentSlide===d.last?d.limit:m?(d.itemW+d.vars.itemMargin)*d.move*d.currentSlide:l?(d.last-d.currentSlide+d.cloneOffset)*g:(d.currentSlide+d.cloneOffset)*g,a=k?p:o,c=k?o:p,b.addEventListener("touchmove",s,!1),b.addEventListener("touchend",t,!1))}function s(b){o=b.touches[0].pageX,p=b.touches[0].pageY,h=k?a-p:a-o,j=k?Math.abs(h)<Math.abs(o-c):Math.abs(h)<Math.abs(p-c);var f=500;(!j||Number(new Date)-i>f)&&(b.preventDefault(),!n&&d.transitions&&(d.vars.animationLoop||(h/=0===d.currentSlide&&0>h||d.currentSlide===d.last&&h>0?Math.abs(h)/g+2:1),d.setProps(e+h,"setTouch")))}function t(){if(b.removeEventListener("touchmove",s,!1),d.animatingTo===d.currentSlide&&!j&&null!==h){var k=l?-h:h,m=k>0?d.getTarget("next"):d.getTarget("prev");d.canAdvance(m)&&(Number(new Date)-i<550&&Math.abs(k)>50||Math.abs(k)>g/2)?d.flexAnimate(m,d.vars.pauseOnAction):n||d.flexAnimate(d.currentSlide,d.vars.pauseOnAction,!0)}b.removeEventListener("touchend",t,!1),a=null,c=null,h=null,e=null}function u(a){a.stopPropagation(),d.animating?a.preventDefault():(d.pause(),b._gesture.addPointer(a.pointerId),q=0,g=k?d.h:d.w,i=Number(new Date),e=m&&l&&d.animatingTo===d.last?0:m&&l?d.limit-(d.itemW+d.vars.itemMargin)*d.move*d.animatingTo:m&&d.currentSlide===d.last?d.limit:m?(d.itemW+d.vars.itemMargin)*d.move*d.currentSlide:l?(d.last-d.currentSlide+d.cloneOffset)*g:(d.currentSlide+d.cloneOffset)*g)}function v(a){a.stopPropagation();var c=a.target._slider;if(c){var d=-a.translationX,f=-a.translationY;return q+=k?f:d,h=q,j=k?Math.abs(q)<Math.abs(-d):Math.abs(q)<Math.abs(-f),a.detail===a.MSGESTURE_FLAG_INERTIA?(setImmediate(function(){b._gesture.stop()}),void 0):((!j||Number(new Date)-i>500)&&(a.preventDefault(),!n&&c.transitions&&(c.vars.animationLoop||(h=q/(0===c.currentSlide&&0>q||c.currentSlide===c.last&&q>0?Math.abs(q)/g+2:1)),c.setProps(e+h,"setTouch"))),void 0)}}function w(b){b.stopPropagation();var d=b.target._slider;if(d){if(d.animatingTo===d.currentSlide&&!j&&null!==h){var f=l?-h:h,k=f>0?d.getTarget("next"):d.getTarget("prev");d.canAdvance(k)&&(Number(new Date)-i<550&&Math.abs(f)>50||Math.abs(f)>g/2)?d.flexAnimate(k,d.vars.pauseOnAction):n||d.flexAnimate(d.currentSlide,d.vars.pauseOnAction,!0)}a=null,c=null,h=null,e=null,q=0}}var a,c,e,g,h,i,j=!1,o=0,p=0,q=0;f?(b.style.msTouchAction="none",b._gesture=new MSGesture,b._gesture.target=b,b.addEventListener("MSPointerDown",u,!1),b._slider=d,b.addEventListener("MSGestureChange",v,!1),b.addEventListener("MSGestureEnd",w,!1)):b.addEventListener("touchstart",r,!1)},resize:function(){!d.animating&&d.is(":visible")&&(m||d.doMath(),n?p.smoothHeight():m?(d.slides.width(d.computedW),d.update(d.pagingCount),d.setProps()):k?(d.viewport.height(d.h),d.setProps(d.h,"setTotal")):(d.vars.smoothHeight&&p.smoothHeight(),d.newSlides.width(d.computedW),d.setProps(d.computedW,"setTotal")))},smoothHeight:function(a){if(!k||n){var b=n?d:d.viewport;a?b.animate({height:d.slides.eq(d.animatingTo).height()},a):b.height(d.slides.eq(d.animatingTo).height())}},sync:function(b){var c=a(d.vars.sync).data("flexslider"),e=d.animatingTo;switch(b){case"animate":c.flexAnimate(e,d.vars.pauseOnAction,!1,!0);break;case"play":c.playing||c.asNav||c.play();break;case"pause":c.pause()}},uniqueID:function(b){return b.find("[id]").each(function(){var b=a(this);b.attr("id",b.attr("id")+"_clone")}),b},pauseInvisible:{visProp:null,init:function(){var a=["webkit","moz","ms","o"];if("hidden"in document)return"hidden";for(var b=0;b<a.length;b++)a[b]+"Hidden"in document&&(p.pauseInvisible.visProp=a[b]+"Hidden");if(p.pauseInvisible.visProp){var c=p.pauseInvisible.visProp.replace(/[H|h]idden/,"")+"visibilitychange";document.addEventListener(c,function(){p.pauseInvisible.isHidden()?d.startTimeout?clearTimeout(d.startTimeout):d.pause():d.started?d.play():d.vars.initDelay>0?setTimeout(d.play,d.vars.initDelay):d.play()})}},isHidden:function(){return document[p.pauseInvisible.visProp]||!1}},setToClearWatchedEvent:function(){clearTimeout(j),j=setTimeout(function(){i=""},3e3)}},d.flexAnimate=function(b,c,f,h,i){if(d.vars.animationLoop||b===d.currentSlide||(d.direction=b>d.currentSlide?"next":"prev"),o&&1===d.pagingCount&&(d.direction=d.currentItem<b?"next":"prev"),!d.animating&&(d.canAdvance(b,i)||f)&&d.is(":visible")){if(o&&h){var j=a(d.vars.asNavFor).data("flexslider");if(d.atEnd=0===b||b===d.count-1,j.flexAnimate(b,!0,!1,!0,i),d.direction=d.currentItem<b?"next":"prev",j.direction=d.direction,Math.ceil((b+1)/d.visible)-1===d.currentSlide||0===b)return d.currentItem=b,d.slides.removeClass(e+"active-slide").eq(b).addClass(e+"active-slide"),!1;d.currentItem=b,d.slides.removeClass(e+"active-slide").eq(b).addClass(e+"active-slide"),b=Math.floor(b/d.visible)}if(d.animating=!0,d.animatingTo=b,c&&d.pause(),d.vars.before(d),d.syncExists&&!i&&p.sync("animate"),d.vars.controlNav&&p.controlNav.active(),m||d.slides.removeClass(e+"active-slide").eq(b).addClass(e+"active-slide"),d.atEnd=0===b||b===d.last,d.vars.directionNav&&p.directionNav.update(),b===d.last&&(d.vars.end(d),d.vars.animationLoop||d.pause()),n)g?(d.slides.eq(d.currentSlide).css({opacity:0,zIndex:1}),d.slides.eq(b).css({opacity:1,zIndex:2}),d.wrapup(q)):(d.slides.eq(d.currentSlide).css({zIndex:1}).animate({opacity:0},d.vars.animationSpeed,d.vars.easing),d.slides.eq(b).css({zIndex:2}).animate({opacity:1},d.vars.animationSpeed,d.vars.easing,d.wrapup));else{var r,s,t,q=k?d.slides.filter(":first").height():d.computedW;m?(r=d.vars.itemMargin,t=(d.itemW+r)*d.move*d.animatingTo,s=t>d.limit&&1!==d.visible?d.limit:t):s=0===d.currentSlide&&b===d.count-1&&d.vars.animationLoop&&"next"!==d.direction?l?(d.count+d.cloneOffset)*q:0:d.currentSlide===d.last&&0===b&&d.vars.animationLoop&&"prev"!==d.direction?l?0:(d.count+1)*q:l?(d.count-1-b+d.cloneOffset)*q:(b+d.cloneOffset)*q,d.setProps(s,"",d.vars.animationSpeed),d.transitions?(d.vars.animationLoop&&d.atEnd||(d.animating=!1,d.currentSlide=d.animatingTo),d.container.unbind("webkitTransitionEnd transitionend"),d.container.bind("webkitTransitionEnd transitionend",function(){clearTimeout(d.ensureAnimationEnd),d.wrapup(q)}),clearTimeout(d.ensureAnimationEnd),d.ensureAnimationEnd=setTimeout(function(){d.wrapup(q)},d.vars.animationSpeed+100)):d.container.animate(d.args,d.vars.animationSpeed,d.vars.easing,function(){d.wrapup(q)})}d.vars.smoothHeight&&p.smoothHeight(d.vars.animationSpeed)}},d.wrapup=function(a){n||m||(0===d.currentSlide&&d.animatingTo===d.last&&d.vars.animationLoop?d.setProps(a,"jumpEnd"):d.currentSlide===d.last&&0===d.animatingTo&&d.vars.animationLoop&&d.setProps(a,"jumpStart")),d.animating=!1,d.currentSlide=d.animatingTo,d.vars.after(d)},d.animateSlides=function(){!d.animating&&q&&d.flexAnimate(d.getTarget("next"))},d.pause=function(){clearInterval(d.animatedSlides),d.animatedSlides=null,d.playing=!1,d.vars.pausePlay&&p.pausePlay.update("play"),d.syncExists&&p.sync("pause")},d.play=function(){d.playing&&clearInterval(d.animatedSlides),d.animatedSlides=d.animatedSlides||setInterval(d.animateSlides,d.vars.slideshowSpeed),d.started=d.playing=!0,d.vars.pausePlay&&p.pausePlay.update("pause"),d.syncExists&&p.sync("play")},d.stop=function(){d.pause(),d.stopped=!0},d.canAdvance=function(a,b){var c=o?d.pagingCount-1:d.last;return b?!0:o&&d.currentItem===d.count-1&&0===a&&"prev"===d.direction?!0:o&&0===d.currentItem&&a===d.pagingCount-1&&"next"!==d.direction?!1:a!==d.currentSlide||o?d.vars.animationLoop?!0:d.atEnd&&0===d.currentSlide&&a===c&&"next"!==d.direction?!1:d.atEnd&&d.currentSlide===c&&0===a&&"next"===d.direction?!1:!0:!1},d.getTarget=function(a){return d.direction=a,"next"===a?d.currentSlide===d.last?0:d.currentSlide+1:0===d.currentSlide?d.last:d.currentSlide-1},d.setProps=function(a,b,c){var e=function(){var c=a?a:(d.itemW+d.vars.itemMargin)*d.move*d.animatingTo,e=function(){if(m)return"setTouch"===b?a:l&&d.animatingTo===d.last?0:l?d.limit-(d.itemW+d.vars.itemMargin)*d.move*d.animatingTo:d.animatingTo===d.last?d.limit:c;switch(b){case"setTotal":return l?(d.count-1-d.currentSlide+d.cloneOffset)*a:(d.currentSlide+d.cloneOffset)*a;case"setTouch":return l?a:a;case"jumpEnd":return l?a:d.count*a;case"jumpStart":return l?d.count*a:a;default:return a}}();return-1*e+"px"}();d.transitions&&(e=k?"translate3d(0,"+e+",0)":"translate3d("+e+",0,0)",c=void 0!==c?c/1e3+"s":"0s",d.container.css("-"+d.pfx+"-transition-duration",c),d.container.css("transition-duration",c)),d.args[d.prop]=e,(d.transitions||void 0===c)&&d.container.css(d.args),d.container.css("transform",e)},d.setup=function(b){if(n)d.slides.css({width:"100%","float":"left",marginRight:"-100%",position:"relative"}),"init"===b&&(g?d.slides.css({opacity:0,display:"block",webkitTransition:"opacity "+d.vars.animationSpeed/1e3+"s ease",zIndex:1}).eq(d.currentSlide).css({opacity:1,zIndex:2}):d.slides.css({opacity:0,display:"block",zIndex:1}).eq(d.currentSlide).css({zIndex:2}).animate({opacity:1},d.vars.animationSpeed,d.vars.easing)),d.vars.smoothHeight&&p.smoothHeight();else{var c,f;"init"===b&&(d.viewport=a('<div class="'+e+'viewport"></div>').css({overflow:"hidden",position:"relative"}).appendTo(d).append(d.container),d.cloneCount=0,d.cloneOffset=0,l&&(f=a.makeArray(d.slides).reverse(),d.slides=a(f),d.container.empty().append(d.slides))),d.vars.animationLoop&&!m&&(d.cloneCount=2,d.cloneOffset=1,"init"!==b&&d.container.find(".clone").remove(),p.uniqueID(d.slides.first().clone().addClass("clone").attr("aria-hidden","true")).appendTo(d.container),p.uniqueID(d.slides.last().clone().addClass("clone").attr("aria-hidden","true")).prependTo(d.container)),d.newSlides=a(d.vars.selector,d),c=l?d.count-1-d.currentSlide+d.cloneOffset:d.currentSlide+d.cloneOffset,k&&!m?(d.container.height(200*(d.count+d.cloneCount)+"%").css("position","absolute").width("100%"),setTimeout(function(){d.newSlides.css({display:"block"}),d.doMath(),d.viewport.height(d.h),d.setProps(c*d.h,"init")},"init"===b?100:0)):(d.container.width(200*(d.count+d.cloneCount)+"%"),d.setProps(c*d.computedW,"init"),setTimeout(function(){d.doMath(),d.newSlides.css({width:d.computedW,"float":"left",display:"block"}),d.vars.smoothHeight&&p.smoothHeight()},"init"===b?100:0))}m||d.slides.removeClass(e+"active-slide").eq(d.currentSlide).addClass(e+"active-slide"),d.vars.init(d)},d.doMath=function(){var a=d.slides.first(),b=d.vars.itemMargin,c=d.vars.minItems,e=d.vars.maxItems;d.w=void 0===d.viewport?d.width():d.viewport.width(),d.h=a.height(),d.boxPadding=a.outerWidth()-a.width(),m?(d.itemT=d.vars.itemWidth+b,d.minW=c?c*d.itemT:d.w,d.maxW=e?e*d.itemT-b:d.w,d.itemW=d.minW>d.w?(d.w-b*(c-1))/c:d.maxW<d.w?(d.w-b*(e-1))/e:d.vars.itemWidth>d.w?d.w:d.vars.itemWidth,d.visible=Math.floor(d.w/d.itemW),d.move=d.vars.move>0&&d.vars.move<d.visible?d.vars.move:d.visible,d.pagingCount=Math.ceil((d.count-d.visible)/d.move+1),d.last=d.pagingCount-1,d.limit=1===d.pagingCount?0:d.vars.itemWidth>d.w?d.itemW*(d.count-1)+b*(d.count-1):(d.itemW+b)*d.count-d.w-b):(d.itemW=d.w,d.pagingCount=d.count,d.last=d.count-1),d.computedW=d.itemW-d.boxPadding},d.update=function(a,b){d.doMath(),m||(a<d.currentSlide?d.currentSlide+=1:a<=d.currentSlide&&0!==a&&(d.currentSlide-=1),d.animatingTo=d.currentSlide),d.vars.controlNav&&!d.manualControls&&("add"===b&&!m||d.pagingCount>d.controlNav.length?p.controlNav.update("add"):("remove"===b&&!m||d.pagingCount<d.controlNav.length)&&(m&&d.currentSlide>d.last&&(d.currentSlide-=1,d.animatingTo-=1),p.controlNav.update("remove",d.last))),d.vars.directionNav&&p.directionNav.update()},d.addSlide=function(b,c){var e=a(b);d.count+=1,d.last=d.count-1,k&&l?void 0!==c?d.slides.eq(d.count-c).after(e):d.container.prepend(e):void 0!==c?d.slides.eq(c).before(e):d.container.append(e),d.update(c,"add"),d.slides=a(d.vars.selector+":not(.clone)",d),d.setup(),d.vars.added(d)},d.removeSlide=function(b){var c=isNaN(b)?d.slides.index(a(b)):b;d.count-=1,d.last=d.count-1,isNaN(b)?a(b,d.slides).remove():k&&l?d.slides.eq(d.last).remove():d.slides.eq(b).remove(),d.doMath(),d.update(c,"remove"),d.slides=a(d.vars.selector+":not(.clone)",d),d.setup(),d.vars.removed(d)},p.init()},a(window).blur(function(){focused=!1}).focus(function(){focused=!0}),a.flexslider.defaults={namespace:"flex-",selector:".slides > li",animation:"fade",easing:"swing",direction:"horizontal",reverse:!1,animationLoop:!0,smoothHeight:!1,startAt:0,slideshow:!0,slideshowSpeed:7e3,animationSpeed:600,initDelay:0,randomize:!1,thumbCaptions:!1,pauseOnAction:!0,pauseOnHover:!1,pauseInvisible:!0,useCSS:!0,touch:!0,video:!1,controlNav:!0,directionNav:!0,prevText:"Previous",nextText:"Next",keyboard:!0,multipleKeyboard:!1,mousewheel:!1,pausePlay:!1,pauseText:"Pause",playText:"Play",controlsContainer:"",manualControls:"",sync:"",asNavFor:"",itemWidth:0,itemMargin:0,minItems:1,maxItems:0,move:0,allowOneSlide:!0,start:function(){},before:function(){},after:function(){},end:function(){},added:function(){},removed:function(){},init:function(){}},a.fn.flexslider=function(b){if(void 0===b&&(b={}),"object"==typeof b)return this.each(function(){var c=a(this),d=b.selector?b.selector:".slides > li",e=c.find(d);1===e.length&&b.allowOneSlide===!0||0===e.length?(e.fadeIn(400),b.start&&b.start(c)):void 0===c.data("flexslider")&&new a.flexslider(this,b)});var c=a(this).data("flexslider");switch(b){case"play":c.play();break;case"pause":c.pause();break;case"stop":c.stop();break;case"next":c.flexAnimate(c.getTarget("next"),!0);break;case"prev":case"previous":c.flexAnimate(c.getTarget("prev"),!0);break;default:"number"==typeof b&&c.flexAnimate(b,!0)}}}(jQuery);
```

Comment: 1) You have invalid HTML. (  the content below the iframe have closing `li` but no opening ). 2) You can't get the duration from an iframe, you have to use the YouTube JS API for this. 3) What have you tried? I see only the slider initialization and nothing related to the video functionality you are requesting?

Comment: 1. I fixed the li

Comment: 2. The duration is 52 seconds

Comment: 3.) So far Ive tried changing the length from 3 to a higher number but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: So you can disable the autoplay of the slider and trigger a next event once those 52s are done. So you can create a `setTimeout` interval with dynamic  delay that will be pulled from the video duration, for example as a data attribute on each slide there will be the duration. Once you autoplay the video you will start the setTimeout function with the pulled duration and you have a working slider.